# Maven: Excluding tests from build

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, compilation

I have some classes I'm using as tests in my src/test/java folder of my project. When I run maven using the standard maven compile plugin. Those items are compiled into .class files and are included in the jar where the compiled code is packaged.

I've created these tests for myself to run within eclipse, prior to running maven and building my release. They are just sanity tests and should not be included in the build. I'd rather not put them in a seperate project, because, to me, they make sense here. How can I tell maven that I do not want it to compile/include the files in that directory?

I beleive the maven compiler plugin is generating the jar as follows:

```
<plugin>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
  <source>1.6</source>
  <target>1.6</target>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Maven excludes compiled tests from your deployable by default. Please include relevant portions of your build file so we can see whats going on with your particular case.

Comment: I'd have to fat finger it in. It's nothing special, as I said it utilizes the default maven compile plugin. There is no 'deployable' in this case other than the jar that houses the .class files. I don't want the Tests to ever be compiled, yet they are, and they are not excluded.

Comment: Well, the tests will *always* be compiled, but like I said, they are excluded by default. What happens when you include `-DskipTests=true` as a command line option?

Comment: Are you sure that the tests are included within your packaged jar file? If you are complying with maven convention (which it sounds like you are by putting your test classes in src/test/java) then they will not be included unless you do something specific to include them.

Comment: @Perception no, tests can be ignored (and so, skip compilation) with -Dmaven.test.skip=true (see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)

Comment: @twillouer - gotcha, and good to know.

Comment: mvn -DskipTests=true install did not seem to work. The tests are still compiled and packaged.

Comment: adding <skipTests>true</skipTests>
to the surefire plugin configuration doesn't do it either

Comment: However, the documentation says that is to skip 'running' tests I want to skip compiling them and packaging them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand from your [comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718264/687514) that the "tests" aren't unit tests, but just ordinary classes that you want excluded from the final artifact? As such, your best option is to make use of the `<exclude>` tag with the [*maven-jar-plugin*](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/yoursortoftestpackage/YourSortOfTestClass*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Comment: SO should I first include this plugin? I beleive right now the maven-compiler-plugin is generating my jar.

Comment: You probably have `<packaging>jar</packaging>` (or if not, the default is `jar` anyways), so the plugin will be implicitly included. Still, it doesn't hurt to lock down the version explicitly (meaning: By all means include it in your `<pluginManagement>` section).

Comment: What are purpose are the *s serving here?

Comment: The `**` wildcards will match any package path (eg. `org/brian/something/`), whereas the single `*` works in the "usual" wildcard manner.

Answer (score 3):

Use the option of `-Dmaven.test.skip` will skip both compilation and execution of the tests. ( use `-DskipTests` just skips the test execution, the tests are still compiled)

[The reference link](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip)

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip`

Answer (score 1):

Annotation for junit   `@Ignore` will ignore the class while building in maven.

Edit:

You can configure [maven-surefire-plugin.](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

```
<project>
<build>
<project>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
        <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Maven will recognize this annotation? I am not using the junit plugin, as my tests are not junit tests. They are simply tests that I have written "manually", so to speak.

Comment: Sorry. Check out the link.

Answer (score 1):

Put your custom test files in a folder `src/localtest/java` i think, maven will not know it is there.

Comment: This would probably work, but I'd like to maintain my directory structure