# Exclude an additional test source from running during build

Tags: java, maven

I added an additional test source directory with the following code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-test-source</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/test/spike</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Which works nicely. BUT I'd like to remove this test directory from executing during   build. I know I can exclude some Tests via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717743/maven-excluding-tests-from-build) but in this case I'd like to remove the whole directory. It seems to me, that the exclude tag only accepts packages. Is there an other way?

The reason I'd like to do this is that the directory only contains some experiments and spikes which should be execute them from IDE on demand but are not required to be executed by the build server (maven).

Comment: If they are only experiments than you shouldn't add them by default. So best i would say is just use them in IDE so no need to add them at all. So no build-helper-maven-plugin needed.

Comment: This is possible, but then everyone else who wants to use this "spike" stuff needs to add the directory manually to the IDE. But its worth to discuss this.

Comment: No for this case i would add a profile for this experimental as already mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different maven profiles. One that includes this test directory, and one that does not.

You could use the first profile in your IDE, and the second profile as the default active profile, when building outside your IDE.

More information on maven profiles:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html